# Amazon sqs queue processing gets repeated but I think it should be executed only once

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an sqs queue defined. I have an api that when someone calls it, lambda pushes an event to sqs queue.

Then the next lambda is connected as trigger to that queue. I am using npm serverless lift package. But my message is processed 3 times, which is not what I expect. I expect the message to be processed once.

In my lambda worker I have the following logic, which I don't know why is executed 3 times (default lift retries). But from my understanding this processing should be marked as success and not execute it 3 times, but only once.

```
export const queueWorkerLambda = async (event: SQSEvent, context: Context) => {
  const records: SQSRecord[] = event.Records;

  const processRecord = async (body) => {
    console.log('processing', body); // executed 3 times, I expect only 1
    return true;
  };
  
  return await Promise.all(
    records.map(async (record) => {
      const body = JSON.parse(record.body);
      return await processRecord(body);
    });
  );

};
```

My logic is that it should process message from the queue and done. Only 1 log. Not retrying to execute it 3 times as I observe in the logs.

Comment: Maybe you need to delete the message after processRecord done?

Comment: @DucNguyen no, the AWS Lambda SQS integration does that automatically, as long as the Lambda function returns a success code.

Comment: @fewfew you should check the visibility timeout parameter present in SQS. The value of that parameter should be greater than lambda timeout.  Post this, as the request is completed it will get  removed from the queue and thus wont be executed again.
reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html